# Disable links until animation is finished to avoid fast clicking on menu that ruins the slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, animation, jquery-animate

I have a slideshow with jQuery Cycle. I've manipulated it quite a bit, so it works totally different than it does by standard.

Now I have a problem. If you click fast though the menu, that activates the slides, it will ruin the slideshow. I need to deactive the menu, until the animations are done. I have a "After-animation" space, where I could put in a "ready"-function of some kind. I just don't know how to.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    after: function(curr,next,opts) {
        //here I can add a "Ready" function i guess
    }       
});
```

Menu: //This is the menu I use. I guess I could add a "Disable menu" rule in here, but again... I don't know how to... :-(

```
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    //$('.slideshow').cycle($(this).parent().index());
    index = $(this).parent().index();
    return false; 

});
```

Or do you have another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work.... not tried it though...

```
var ready = false;

$('.slideshow').cycle({
    after: function(curr,next,opts) {
        //here I can add a "Ready" function i guess
        ready = true;
    }       
});

$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    if (! ready ) { return false; }
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    //$('.slideshow').cycle($(this).parent().index());
    index = $(this).parent().index();
    ready = false;
    return false; 

});
```

Comment: Without the if (! ready ) { return false; }
it worked like a charm... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply show/hide a transparent div with high z-index value that would disable links on your page as described here:

http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2009/02/disable-all-page-elements-with.html

Comment: I would like to do it with pure js to avoid to make unnessesary markup.